# Вычислить столбец datetime в зависимости от значения в другом столбце

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Необходимо прибавить к столбцу с типом datetime определенное количество часов в зависимости от данных в столбце Локация. Т.е. если в столбце локация А то прибавляем 1 час, если Б то 2.
Есть словарь с локацией и сколько необходимо прибавить.
Словарь:

```py
dict_tz = {'UL':timedelta(minutes=120),'BL':timedelta(minutes=300),'SL':timedelta(minutes=240),
           'WSL':timedelta(minutes=120),'EL':timedelta(minutes=420),'WUL':timedelta(minutes=120)}
```

Пробовал так:

```py
df['GMT'] = df['GMT'].apply(lambda x: x + dict_tz.get(df['Location'],timedelta(minutes=0)))
```

Текст ошибки:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c6daa8fd5423> in <module>()
      1 df['GMT'] = df['StartDate']
----> 2 df['GMT'] = df['GMT'].apply(lambda x: x + dict_tz.get(df['Location'],timedelta(minutes=0)))
      3 #df['GMT'] = dict_tz.get(df['Location'],datetime.time(0,0,0))
      4 df

2 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __hash__(self)
   1884         raise TypeError(
   1885             "{0!r} objects are mutable, thus they cannot be"
-> 1886             " hashed".format(self.__class__.__name__)
   1887         )
   1888 

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: приведите пример данных

Comment: StartDate = 2017-12-28 15:40:05

Comment: df.head(), например. И результат в вопрос. Если нужно, поменяйте данные

Comment: а что обозначает `UL`, `BL`, `WSL`?

Comment: ```python
StartDate Location
0 2018-11-07 06:56:10 CBL
1 2018-11-07 07:41:52 CBL
2 2018-11-07 07:47:21 CBL
3 2018-11-07 09:18:13 CBL
4 2018-11-07 09:12:43 CBL

Comment: `df['GMT'] + df['location'].map(dict_tz)`

Comment: Можно как-то добавить, если такого ключа нет, то дефолтное значение "такое" ? Например как вот в этой конструкции : dict_tz.get(df['Location'],timedelta(minutes=0))

Comment: MaxU, просто код локации

Comment: @rozhalin, я когда-то делал что-то подобное, но вместо непонятного кода локации у меня были коды временных зон. У вас есть коды временных зон, которые соответствуют вашим локациям?

Comment: @MaxU, я могу сделать если нужно.

Comment: @rozhalin, да лучше все стандартизировать. Лучше использовать названия временных зон, которые присутствуют в `pytz.all_timezones`

Comment: @MaxU, как я могу потом это использовать? Как должен выглядеть словарь тогда?

Comment: Если у вас в DataFrame есть информация о временной зоне в стандартном виде, например `'Europe/Kiev'`, то можно воспользоваться векторизированными функциями Pandas для перевода времени между разоичными временными зонами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример с переводом времени из GMT в различные временные зоны:

```
In [52]: import pytz

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
                  GMT             TZ
0 2018-11-07 06:56:10    Europe/Kiev
1 2018-11-07 07:41:52   Europe/Minsk
2 2018-11-07 07:47:21  Europe/Berlin
3 2018-11-07 09:18:13    Europe/Kiev
4 2018-11-07 09:12:43  Europe/Berlin

In [54]: df["Time_TZ"] = (
    ...:     df
    ...:     .groupby("TZ")
    ...:     ["GMT"]
    ...:     .apply(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize(pytz.timezone("GMT"))
    ...:                       .dt.tz_convert(pytz.timezone(x.name))))
    ...:

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
                  GMT             TZ                    Time_TZ
0 2018-11-07 06:56:10    Europe/Kiev  2018-11-07 08:56:10+02:00
1 2018-11-07 07:41:52   Europe/Minsk  2018-11-07 10:41:52+03:00
2 2018-11-07 07:47:21  Europe/Berlin  2018-11-07 08:47:21+01:00
3 2018-11-07 09:18:13    Europe/Kiev  2018-11-07 11:18:13+02:00
4 2018-11-07 09:12:43  Europe/Berlin  2018-11-07 10:12:43+01:00
```

---

```
In [62]: df.loc[0, "Time_TZ"]
Out[62]: Timestamp('2018-11-07 08:56:10+0200', tz='Europe/Kiev')

In [63]: type(df.loc[0, "Time_TZ"])
Out[63]: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

In [64]: df.dtypes
Out[64]:
GMT        datetime64[ns]
TZ                 object
Time_TZ            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Какой тип данных Time_TZ?